# Test Facebook Authentication from jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I get this error message when i run try to authenticate facebook app from jsfiddle

***Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains***.

**http://jsfiddle.net/MyNameIsSakthi/K5hwY/1/**

```
while(1){
   print("Thanks for answering!");
}
```

*what must be the settings to be changes in Facebook App ?*

[image]

Comment: Looks like some missconfiguration within the app itself.

Comment: This works fine to me! What's the problem?

Comment: @FexdelSollo : It works fine if i run the app inside facebook. The problem occurs only in jsfiddle!

Comment: Rather than using jsfiddle for this (which others have pointed out you need to configure the url correctly in the developer portal) Facebook do have a javascript test console themselves https://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/ which might be easier to use. The point of this is that it ties your app to your domain. Otherwise someone could take your app details and pretend to be your app on another domain. If I were you I would stick away from using a "public" site like jsfiddle for this or make sure you delete it as an allowed url straight after you're done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@sakthi in the facebook app configuration, we need to add the domain name where our app runs. In case of jsfiddle, though the website url is jsfiddle.net, when we run the app, the output will run in an iframe where the code of the iframe is running from the website "http://fiddle.jshell.net". So add this url in the Website with Facebook Login of facebook app settings. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your app is not configured to work on jsfiddle.

In your app settings, you will need to change the `domain` and the URL for `website with Facebook login` to reflect the domain and URL of jsfiddle

Just note, that if you make this change to your app, it won't work wherever you currently have it set up.  You may want to make a new app to use just on jsfiddle